# Save search terms on a web page

Tags: search

I would like to save the search terms entered by the user on our site so the next time they perform similar search their previous search terms will be listed as reference, a bit similar to what Google is offering on their search.

Is using cookie the right approach here? Are there any other suggestion to this?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie will only give them their own search terms, if that is what you want then yes. If you want to show the trending/popular search terms of all users/a subset of users (same region), then you have to do it serverside, probably with ajax.

200ms after the user stops typing / when he finished a word (or your own arbitrary rule) send an ajax query to your server to obtain search terms with that word.